# Vectorizing R code, which already uses sequence notation

Tags: r, vectorization

I am struggling to write fast code to compute a function of the following vector:

[image]

Currently I code it using for loop, which is very slow:

```
rho <- 0.9
E_D <- numeric(100)
E_D[1] <- 1
for (t in 2:100){
  summm <- sum(cumsum(0.9^(0:(t-2)))^2)
  E_D[t] <- t+exp(summm)
}
```

summm is the element of the vector I analytically defined in the picture above. E_D is a vector, which is some function of that vector. If I set maximum t to 5000, then the code above runs for more than 1 sec on my machine, which is too slow for my purposes.

I tried `data.table` solution, but it can not accommodate intermediate vector output within a cell:

```
tempdt <- data.table(prd=2:100 ,summm=0)
tempdt[, summm:=sum(cumsum(rho^(0:(prd-2)))^2)]
Warning message:
In 0:(prd - 2) : numerical expression has 99 elements: only the first used
```

How to make the code above faster? Please do not tell me that I have to do it in Matlab...

EDIT: To clarify, I need to compute the following vector:

[image]

Comment: The `prd` is more. than one element, you need to do an `lapply` or `sapply`

Comment: @akrun But isn't ```lapply``` as slow as for loop? The only point of me trying to use```data.table``` is to make the code faster than for loop.

Comment: there is a `sequence` function but that is also doing `lapply` behind the hood

Comment: I am not sure if you need to take `cumsum` before taking `sum`. Can you do the calculation manually for 3-5 values and include their output in your post.

Comment: I added the picture with the first 4 elements of a vector I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
n <- 100L
cp <- cumprod(rep(0.9, n - 1L)) / 0.9
cssq <- cumsum(cp)^2
cumsum(cssq)
```

truncated output:

```
[1]    1.00000    4.61000   11.95410   23.78082   40.55067   62.50542   89.72283  122.15959 ...
```

Comment: I guess the last `sum` is taking. the full `sum` right?

Comment: From what I understand in the formula, the `+` is for each iteration.  i.e. the reason I said a loop is. needed,  but I like your approach with `cumprod`

Comment: @ chinsoon12 By curly brackets I meant that this is a vector with 99 elements. The first element corresponds to t=2, the last one corresponds to t=100. Each element is computed using the equation above.

Comment: I still do not understand why you use ```cumprod```.

Comment: I have added picture the explain the composition of the vector. I apologize for confusion.

Comment: i think this maybe just needs another `cumsum`

Comment: at last ... I knew there would be a geometric sequences answer : `tempdt[, summ2 := cumsum(((1 - rho^(prd-1))/(1-rho))^2)]` but still slower than yours

Comment: @user20650, it shouldnt be slower. doesnt that series sum infinite number of terms? the closest that i could find was something like 1 / (1 - x)

Comment: does it not sums up the first n terms

Comment: @user20650, ah differencing of 2 series. i think there is something wrong with the context of the timing. maybe its because n is small.

Comment: nope tried it for large N - yours is still faster. I changed the `^` to your approach : `tempdt[, summ3 := cumsum(((1 - cumprod(rep(rho, N-1)))/(1-rho))^2)]` and it is more competitive ... for N>1e6 this approach (with your amendment) is a bit faster but very little difference

Comment: @user20650 thanks for the info! I think you should post this as an answer. mathematical answers are always elegant

Comment: ... you have given a good answer. This was me just stubbornly trying to remember sequences and series stuffs. Similar to you, I was surprised that it was slower though

Comment: @user20650 i think its because of R. If these are implemented in pure low level language like C, your solution should be faster

Answer (score 1):

The `:` is not vectorized.  We may need to either loop with `sapply/lapply` or do a group by row

```
library(data.table)
tempdt[, summm := sum(cumsum(rho^(0:(prd-2)))^2), seq_len(nrow(tempdt))]
head(tempdt)
#   prd    summm
#1:   2  1.00000
#2:   3  4.61000
#3:   4 11.95410
#4:   5 23.78082
#5:   6 40.55067
#6:   7 62.50542
```

Comment: While this solution is more elegant than for loop, it runs with the same speed. Do you know about any way to compute summm in the faster way?

Comment: @MoyseyAbramowitz try with `sequence` as it is optimized, but then again it is a loop